# How to add cell to pd.DataFrame but keep the type (np.uint64) of value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, types

when I have a DataFrame with np.uint64 values

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])
df.a = [1, 3]
df.b = [1, 3]
df = df.astype({'a': np.uint64, 'b': np.uint64})
print(df.info())
```

it returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   a       2 non-null      uint64
 1   b       2 non-null      uint64
dtypes: uint64(2)
memory usage: 160.0 bytes
None
```

When I now try to add a cell to the DataFrame:

```
x = np.uint64(5)
print(type(x))
```

returns

```
<class 'numpy.uint64'>
```

and

```
df.at[2, 'a'] = x
print(type(df.at[2, 'a']))
print(df.dtypes)
```

returns

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   a       3 non-null      float64
 1   b       2 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 180.0 bytes
None
```

Why does the type of the columns and values change from np.uint64 to float64?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because when you do:

```
x = np.uint64(5)
df.at[2, 'a'] = x
```

It generates a NaN for column B and pandas does not allow NaN to be integers which is what uint(64).

If you do add a row that does not have any nulls and convert the dataframe back to unit64 it will allow that:

```
df = df.astype({'a': np.uint64, 'b': np.uint64})
```

If that answers your question please mark as a solution!

Answer (score 0):

## Update and following question:

My solution to solve the problem:

Instead of using `np.uint64` values I cast them beforehand to `np.int64`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])
df.a = [1, 3]
df.b = [1, 3]
df = df.astype({'a': np.int64, 'b': np.int64})
print(df.dtypes)
# a    int64
# b    int64
# dtype: object
```

In case one I add again one value:

```
x = np.int64(5)
print(type(x))  # <class 'numpy.int64'>
df.at[2, 'a'] = x
print(type(df.at[2, 'a']))  # <class 'numpy.float64'>
print(df.dtypes)
# a    float64
# b    float64
# dtype: object
```

Again, both columns are cast to float because `NaN` does not allow integers. Right?

But in case two, when I do the following instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])
df.a = [1, 3]
df.b = [1, 3]
df = df.astype({'a': np.int64, 'b': np.int64})
print(df.dtypes)
# a    int64
# b    int64
# dtype: object

df_row = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])
df_row.a = [5]
df_row.b = [5]
print(df_row.dtypes)
# a    int64
# b    int64
# dtype: object

df = df.append(df_row, ignore_index=True)
print(df.dtypes)
# a    int64
# b    int64
# dtype: object
```

it means that with append in this situation the dataframe does not change the datatype.

But again, if do the same with `np.uint64`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])
df.a = [1, 3]
df.b = [1, 3]
df = df.astype({'a': np.uint64, 'b': np.uint64})
print(df.dtypes)
# a    uint64
# b    uint64
# dtype: object

df_row = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])
df_row.a = [np.uint64(5)]
df_row.b = [np.uint64(5)]
print(df_row.dtypes)
# a    int64
# b    int64
# dtype: object

df = df.append(df_row, ignore_index=True)
print(df.dtypes)
# a    float64
# b    float64
# dtype: object
```

The columns types of `df_row` explains that later at the `append`the types are changed to `float64`

But why is the datatype in `df_row.a = [np.uint64(5)]` changed to `int64`?